# Give $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs of the following

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, continuity

Give $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs of the following

$f(x)= \frac{x+1}{x^2-x}$

**Prove $f$ is continuous at each point a in $[2, \infty)$**

I write out $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$, and I get $\left|\frac{x+1}{x^2-x}-\frac{a+1}{a^2-a}\right|<\epsilon$

However, however I tried, I still can't derive a $|x-a|$ from $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$

I also tried to set a $\delta$. But I failed to find a equality.

Any hint on this one?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
\begin{align}
(a^2 - a)(x+1) - (x^2 - x)(a+1) &= a^2 x + a^2 - ax - a - ax^2 + ax - x^2 + x\\
&= ax(a - x) + (a + x)(a - x) - (a - x)
\end{align}

Comment: That should do it. +1

Answer (score 1):

Let $a \geq 2$. If $x \geq 2$, then
$$
\bigg| \frac{x+1}{x^{2}-x} - \frac{a+1}{a^{2}-a} \bigg| = \frac{a|x-a||x+a|}{(x^{2}-x)(a^{2}-a)} \leq \frac{|x-a||x+a|}{a-1};
$$
if in addition $|x-a| < 1$, then $|x| < a+1$, implying $|x+a| \leq |x|+a < 2a+1$, implying
$$
\frac{|x-a||x+a|}{a-1} < |x-a|\bigg( \frac{2a+1}{a-1} \bigg) =: |x-a|\delta_{1,a};
$$
given any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $|x-a|\delta_{1,a} < \varepsilon$ if in addition $|x-a| < \varepsilon/\delta_{1,a}$. Hence, in conclusion, for every $a \geq 2$ and every $\varepsilon > 0$ it holds that $x \geq 2$ and $|x-a| < \min \{ 1, \delta_{1,a} \}$ imply $|f(x) - f(a)| < \varepsilon$; we have proved the continuity of $f$ at every $a \geq 2$.